# Get days in a month using ionic date picker

Tags: ionic2

I need to get only the day that is been selected in ionic date picker, in model I am able to see year, but when I set `displayFormat="DD"` I am getting empty object.

I need only selected date should be pushed to model not year.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY DD" min="2016"  name="dd" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

The above code returns only the year not the date.

Answer (score 0):

Try date-fns library for getting date or day.
 
`import * as DayOfMonth from "date-fns";`
DayOfMonth is a method will return the day.
 for ex- 15-02-2017 will return 15.